# splitting background over multiple divs on android

Tags: android, html, css

I am struggling a while on this one for now. I want to have one background spread over multiple separate divs. I achieved to get it working on all devices and browsers except for al the major browsers on android devices. Am I missing  something?

desired and working result on all devises except android: 
[image: exemple]

```css
.child {
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
margin: 5px;
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #F17C58, #E94584, #24AADB, #27DBB1, #FFDC18, #FF3706);
background-size: 600% 100%;
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
float:left
}
.child:nth-child(3n+1) {
clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
<div class="child">
</div>
<div class="child">
</div>
<div class="child">
</div>
<div class="child">
</div>
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code above produces the following, which doesn't seem to be what you're after: https://jsfiddle.net/fzy1ba2e/

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out sir, I improved my question as suggested by  the answer posted by Ranjith v in order to produce the same output as the picture. However this was not the key issue as the above effect as seen in the snippet does not replicate on android devices however it does work on android devices but only with the firefox browser. I prefer to stay away of firefox though as the js performs laggy on it.

Answer (score 1):

pls try this. i added here float left for child div

```
<style>
.child
{
  height:80px;
  width:80px;
  margin:5px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,#F17C58,#E94584,#24AADB,#27DBB1,#FFDC18,#FF3706);
  background-size: 600% 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  float:left;
}
.child:nth-child(3n+1){
  clear:left;
}
</style>

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div>
   <div class="child">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out sir, I added your improvements to my question as this does not cover the key issue of this question.